# change image inside PictureBox control at runtime

Tags: winforms

I have a PictureBox control inside a windows form. I set an image at design time, but want to change it at runtime. I set up this function, which is being executed, but the image does not change. Any idea why??

```
public void RefreshImage()
    {
        pbPreview.Image = Image.FromFile("C:/test.jpg");
    }
```

Edit: ok, this is getting weird. I've added a line to the code, for testing purposes:

```
pbPreview.Image = Image.FromFile("C:/test.jpg");
pbPreview.ImageLocation = "http://www.indianorphanages.net/images/india-political-map.gif";
```

Now the first image (test.jpg) appears, for about a second, then gets overwritten by the second one (map.gif). Apparently the Image.FromFile line is working, but some kind of refresh is needed. I tried

```
this.Refresh();
```

but it had no effect either.

Comment: Hmm, it works in your 2nd snippet but not in the first?

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code and these are my results.

**On button press:**

[image]

**After a few second:**

[image]

The code is fetching the second map from the web hence the delay. This is not a refresh. You are able to use forward slashes in file paths, so syntax is not the problem.

I think you just have conflicting statements for the picture box regarding the source of the image:

```
//Pick one of these, they are both image setters

pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:/Users/justin/Desktop/jMSrb.jpg");
pictureBox1.ImageLocation = "http://www.indianorphanages.net/images/india-political-map.gif";
```